# iOS Swift 3: Custom UIButton using xib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, custom-controls

I created a custom UIButton like this:

```
import UIKit

class HomeButton: UIButton {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewBG: UIView!

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 22

    @IBInspectable var bgColor: UIColor? = UIColor.white{
        didSet{
            viewBG.backgroundColor = bgColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: fontSize)
    }


    func setup() {
        let view = loadViewFromNib(nibName: "HomeButton") as! SpringButton
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)

        self.clipsToBounds = true

        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(K.CORNER_RADIUS)  

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

}
```

and here's my xib file for HomeButton, I also named it HomeButton.xib
[image: xib]

Here's SpringButton class

```
import UIKit

class SpringButton: UIButton {

   open var minimumScale: CGFloat = 0.95
   open var pressSpringDamping: CGFloat = 0.4
   open var releaseSpringDamping: CGFloat = 0.35
   open var pressSpringDuration = 0.4
   open var releaseSpringDuration = 0.5

public init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.pressSpringDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: self.pressSpringDamping, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.minimumScale, y: self.minimumScale)
    }, completion: nil)
}

override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.releaseSpringDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: self.releaseSpringDamping, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
}

override open func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let location = touches.first!.location(in: self)
    if !self.bounds.contains(location) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.releaseSpringDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: self.releaseSpringDamping, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

override open func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.releaseSpringDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: self.releaseSpringDamping, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
}

}
```

In SpringButton, I override functions: touchesBegan, touchesEnded, touchesMoved, touchesCancelled to animate the button when click, but those functions are never called. Why? Am I doing this correctly or should I do any other way?

To use the HomeButton, I just create an IBOutlet button in the storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

I need to create the custom button this way because I'll later add an image on the left and another icon on the right, so it's easy to customize the button the way I want.

Comment: enable user interaction to that view or button and make your xib file same as your class..you are using as SpringButton..

Comment: oh I see, but when I enable user interaction in the Spring Button, I cannot receive @IBAction event in my controller

Comment: add springButton class also

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: You have created a new class of button called "Home Button", but where is the class for "Spring Button"? Please post the code for Spring button also.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now your customized button's class is `HomeButton` so it does not response functions you override in `SpringButton`.

As @karthikeyan say you need change your customized button's class to `SpringButton` in inspector.

Comment: Oh I see. Should I change the HomeButton class to extends UIView instead of UIButton?